# sending variable from one routes to another in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use a variable from one routes to another routes.

I want to do this without using Global variable

```
    app.post('/value',function(req,res,next){
          var name = "rupesh";  /// i want to use this varible in '/name'
          // do some thing
    });

     app.get('/next',function(req,res){
          // do something here;
     });

     app.post('/name',function(req,res){

         res.send(name);   //this name is obtains from '/value'
     });
```

I am stuck here.

Someone please help me?

Comment: This is called ["keeping session information"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)) and there are packages available for express or whatever framework to do this. You should search and read up on them

Comment: @NeilLunn ,can u tell me the package for express frameworks

Comment: We don't do recommendations here. Type "express session" into your favorite search engine and start browsing and reading.

Comment: why you want this can you tell this in question? Does you want to call the `/name` from `/value` .

Comment: no i just want to use the variable stored in /value in /name